# Angular 6 - Error using http.get responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, httpclient, response

I'd like to make an observable like this in (angular 5).
How can I declare `responseType` in Angular 6?

**The Angular 5 code:**

```
public ExportSomeThing(
        ano: number
    ): Observable<IDownloadArquivo> {
        let q = this.http
            .get(this.apiUrl + ano + '/pordia/excel', {
                responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob  // <<<-- This code
            }).map((res) => {
```

**My angular 6 code:**

```
public MyExport(
    ano: number
  ): Observable<IXpto> {
    let q = this.http
      .get( this.api_rul + ano + '/some_path/', {
        responseType: "ResponseContentType.Blob"  // <<<--- error here !!!
      }).map((res) => {
```

**The  error is:**

```
[ts]
Argument of type '{ responseType: "ResponseContentType.Blob"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.
  Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible.
    Type '"ResponseContentType.Blob"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.
```

**How can I make my `http.get` similar in Angular 6?**

I'm trying to download Excel method!

Comment: apparently the enum is deprecated, as it says in the enum description. now writing `responseType: 'blob'` is enough. Be careful not to use generic parameter for the get/post method call, since now the return type is obvious no generic parameter is needed. anyone who came here see: https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data

Answer (score 6):

Workaround Angular 8

Client Side:

```
 getBlob(url: string): Observable<Blob> {
        return this.http.get<Blob>(url, { observe: 'body', responseType: 'blob' as 'json' })
 }
```

Note the 'blob' as 'json' trick

Server Side returns byte[]:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/api/someApi")
public @ResponseBody byte[] GetBlob() {

     byte[] ret  = this.service.getData();
     return ret; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Very good explanation is given [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586). Try below code

```
  public getRequest(urlPath: string): Observable<any> {

    const options = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': token  // if you have to give token
        }),

        // Ignore this part or  if you want full response you have 
        // to explicitly give as 'boby'as http client by default give res.json()
        observe:'response' as 'body',

       // have to explicitly give as 'blob' or 'json'
        responseType: 'blob' as 'blob'  
    };

     // resObj should be of type Blob
    return this.http.get(urlPath, options)
        .map((resObj: Blob) => resObj)
        .catch((errorObj: any) => Observable.throw(errorObj || 'Server error'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace "ResponseContentType.Blob" by 'blob'

```
this.http.get( this.api_rul + ano + '/some_path/', {
    responseType: 'blob'
  }).map((res) => {})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how we can add **responseType** in **Angular 6+** versions,

```
const httpOptions = {
     headers: new HttpHeaders({
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     }),
     observe: 'response' as 'body',
     responseType: 'blob' as 'blob'
};

return this.httpClient.get("API_URL", httpOptions);
```

For more, you can refer [here](https://github.com/imchandanys/Files-Upload/blob/master/FileUploadWeb/src/app/FileUpload/file-upload-framework/service/to-local-folder.service.ts).

Answer (score 0):

try this. works well for me...

```
public post(data?: any, useHeaders: boolean = true, contentType: HttpContentTypeEnum = HttpContentTypeEnum.Json, responseType: HttpResponseTypeEnum = HttpResponseTypeEnum.Json): Observable<any> {

    try {

        if (useHeaders) {

            let resonseType: any;
            let headers: HttpHeaders;

            switch (contentType) {

                case HttpContentTypeEnum.Json: {

                    headers = new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "application/json" });

                    break;
                }
            }

            switch (responseType) {

                case HttpResponseTypeEnum.Text: {

                    resonseType = 'text';

                    break;
                }

                case HttpResponseTypeEnum.Json: {

                    resonseType = 'json';

                    break;
                }

                case HttpResponseTypeEnum.Blob: {

                    resonseType = 'blob';

                    break;
                }
            } 

            return this.http.post(this._baseUri, data, { responseType: resonseType, headers: headers }).pipe(catchError((err: any) => {
                if (err.status === 401) {

                    return Observable.throw('Unauthorized');
                }
            }));
        }
        else {

            return this.http.post(this._baseUri, data).pipe(catchError((err: any) => {
                if (err.status === 401) {

                    return Observable.throw('Unauthorized');
                }
            }));
        }
    } catch (err) {

        //console.log((<Error>e).message);
    }
}
```